# Is it possible to edit .java files in cordova-plugin-background-mode?

Tags: android, ionic3, cordova-plugins, foreground-service

I am using cordova-plugin-background-mode in my app. Now I am facing "bad notifications channel' issue in my app. When I checked about this issue, I found out that some changes in Foregroundservice.java which is inside cordova-plugin-background-mode will fix the issue.

But i have doubt that is it possible to edit the native Android codes of cordova-plugin-background-mode in offline?

Is it possible to install those plugins in offline?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the [GitHub page](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) for this plugin and use the **Fork** button to clone this project to your Github account, and then you are free to commit any change you want to the master branch to the now forked project.

In your `package.json`, you will then have to change the source of the plugin to the forked one in your github account, for example:

```
    (...)
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-background-mode": "git+https://github.com/your_github_username/cordova-plugin-background-mode.git",
    (...)
```

where your_github_username should be replaced with your Github username.

After that you need to run `npm install` again to reinstall the plugin.

You may also need to remove the old installed plugin before, as I have had problems with this before, I've deleted the `plugins/` and `node_modules/` directories in project root.

Or if you don't want to remove all of it, you can try removing only `plugins/cordova-plugin-background-mode/` and `node_modules/cordova-plugin-background-mode/`

Then you will need to run `npm install` and `ionic cordova run <platform>`.

Eg. script if you're using android platform for Linux bash, run it from project root:

```
rm -rf plugins/cordova-plugin-background-mode/
rm -rf node_modules/cordova-plugin-background-mode/
npm install
ionic cordova run android
```

Use `ionic cordova run ios` instead if your platform is iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to edit the file. But you need to make a separate git repo for the plugin and install the plugin from that repo.

You need to keep your new repository for plugin public and in add the plugin in package.json for example `cordova-plugin-background-mode": "git+url_of_public_git_repo"`